# Low disk space in root file system error

Tags: release-freya, disk-management

I have allocated a huge amount of space on my hard disk for elementary OS, as can be seen in GParted image. However, I get the message of "insufficient space" for the file system.

[image: Low space message]
(low disk space in << Root file system >>)

When I installed elementary OS Freya 3 years ago, I gave it all one of my two discs, and did the automatic installation.

[image: GParted graphic information]

**How can this happen, and how can I correct it?** The system works perfectly well. ***Is it a false message and is there really no problem?*** That space increased from 340 Mb to 1.1 Gb when erasing old kernels.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved. I formatted an NTFS partition as ext4 and moved to it many files, so I have enough free space now.